# How do you know if your Windows Server 2008 R2 Software RAID has failed?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, software-raid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you monitor the health of a mirrored disk in Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/149917/how-do-you-monitor-the-health-of-a-mirrored-disk-in-windows)

I have software RAID (RAID-1) enabled on 2 pairs of Drives on Windows Home Server 2008 R2. To test the redundancy, I unplugged a drive while the server was running. About 30 seconds later Disk Manager reported the break in fault tolerance. However, nothing was written to the event log.

I was hoping to find a way to alert me via email when something was wrong with software RAID, but it appears there isn't an easy way to do this if nothing is written to the event log.

Does anyone know how to monitor for Software RAID failures on Windows?

Comment: believe me its in the logs, if not in the standard log then look under the application and services logs.

Comment: believe me it's not. see http://blog.gerhards.net/2009/10/will-microsoft-remove-windows-software.html

Comment: wow haven't used a software raid for 10+ years!  Kinda seems stupid that MS would do this.

Comment: Did you look in the Hardware Events log?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct this error is not logged or able to alert via SMTP through Windows.

One thing you can look to do is try to setup alerting via your RAID controller.

Additionally most manufacturers such as Dell/HP have some monitoring software on the hardware level that you can configure to generate alerts upon hardware failure.

Hope this helps it is an unfortunate issue that Microsoft seems to have no interest in resolving.

Answer (score 1):

Relying on the Event Log for checking if your software mirror is still working always seemed like a kludge to me. I hardly ever used software RAID in Windows (it lacked the necessary manageability features), but always thought that using a WMI class for monitoring would be a better idea. A short research shows that there is [Win32_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a promising "Availability" property.

You should be able to create an event filter and register an event comsumer like [described in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from that, if you really need to (i.e. if you are not using some monitoring solution which is capable of querying WMI on periodic invervals and send alerts).